# Google mod_pagespeed for ajax loaded content

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I`m trying to optimze and convert images using mod_pagespeed and it works very good for all  tags in html files. But how could it process images that loaded with js? For example images in slideshows and etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_pagespeed normally optimizes images and other resources by detecting their URL in the HTML and then replacing the URL with a link to the optimized version. As of mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.1 however, mod_pagespeed includes a feature called [In-Place Resource Optimization](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#ipro), which allows resources requested with their original URL to be optimized. This can be used in cases like yours where images are being requested through AJAX. It can be enabled by setting `ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization on` in your config file, and have a look at the documentation linked above for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to docs this feature is what it need. But unfortunately it isn`t working. Maybe some system problems on dev server.

Comment: Reach out to us on our [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss) if you're having issues with this feature and we'll be happy to help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

Google's mod_pagespeed module only parses HTML files for images, and then optimizes them.  You would have to have the images loaded via the HTML file, and then referenced/shown to the client via javascript. (Have the images hidden by default).