# serving images from S3 and optimize (cache, scale) via pagespeed

Tags: apache, nginx, amazon-s3, pagespeed

I'm giving out big images and resizing it on the client.

Today I found pagespeed can resize the image and offer it to client.
Well, that sounded great, but it isn't that easy to set it up.

Here's what happens now.

```
1. client request page
2. with ajax or json inside the initial page response, image url is provided
3. image url is at aws s3 (or I could set that image url to point to my server and proxy it)
```

How do I make it as following..

```
1. client request page
2. ajax
3. image url point to my server
4. upon image request, my server gets the image from s3
5. perform the optimization as if the image was obtained from local (resize, cache)
6. give it to the user
```

[PageSpeed and CDN images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132351/pagespeed-and-cdn-images)
[Google mod_pagespeed for ajax loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076663/google-mod-pagespeed-for-ajax-loaded-content)
https://superuser.com/questions/768040/https-proxy-s3-aws-via-nginx-with-pagespeed

https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=599

seems to point to an answer, but hard to get my head around it...

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Anatoly: no, gave up for now..

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Nginx S3 proxy and Nginx image filter module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html

Comment: nginx image filter seems to create images of specific size. pagespeed seems to make images of needed size by looking at html source. (I need to do it over ajax though)